# Quartz. Fire stateful out of normal schedule but respecting non-concurrent execution restriction

Tags: quartz.net

Configuration
Quartz.net 2.0.1
JobStore: SqlServer

Statefull jobs are running inside a windows service. 
There is also a console application that allow firing the same jobs inside service. 
I want to initialize correctly quartz scheduler so that it will respect non-concurrent job execution while allowing to fire a certain job immediately from console.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you mark your job with the DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute attribute, you can schedule your jobs from any source you want and the scheduler will make sure only one instance runs at a time.